# How to combine GetIntent.GetAction() and enableForegroundDispatch on same class?

Tags: android, tags, nfc

In my android app, once android manifest detects the nfc tag, it opens the `loginactivity` class.

`loginactivity` uses `(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {}` to run the various functions on the tag.

I would also like to implement nfc tag detection on the page itself using `intentfilter` and `enableForegroundDispatch`

How do i combine both types of nfc detection in the same class?

What i think might work:

```
  if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
    onNewIntent(GetIntent());   
     }
else{
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,new Intent(this,getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP),0);
    IntentFilter ndef = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);
    intentFiltersArray= new IntentFilter[] {ndef, };
    techListsArray = new String[][] {new String[] {IsoDep.class.getName()}};

}
```

Of course the onPause and onResume has enable foreground dispacth.

Is this the correct way to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily combine both methods (using NFC discovery intents in your application manifest to get your activity started upon detection of NFC tags and using foreground dispatch to receive events while your activity is visible in the foreground).

For the manifest part you would do something like this (or adapted to whatever event you want to trigger upon):

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
</intent-filter>
<meta-data android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
           android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
```

And your nfc_tech_filter.xml could look like this (or adapted to whatever tag technology you want to trigger upon):

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.IsoDep</tech>
    </tech-list>
</resources>
```

Then, in your activity's `onCreate()`, `onStart()` or `onResume()` method, you would grab the intent and feed it to your intent handling method. That could look something like this:

```
handleIntent(getIntent());
```

In order to use the foreground dispatch, you would register the for the foreground dispatch system in your activity's `onResume()` method (don't forget to unregister in `onPause()`!):

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
NfcAdapter nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, null, null);
```

Alternatively you could also only register for TECH_DISCOVERED intents with IsoDep technology (like in the manifest):

```
nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent,
    new IntentFilter[] { new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED) },
    new String[][] { new String[] { IsoDep.class.getName() } }
);
```

Then you will receive NFC intents in your activity's `onNewIntent()` method. Thus, you would instruct your intent handler to process those intents too:

```
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    handleIntent(intent);
}
```

Finally, you could use an intent handler like this, to process the intents:

```
private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if ((intent.getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) == 0) {
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action) ||
            NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {

            // do something ...

        }
    }
}
```